# Checking if string is null or undefined always returns False

Tags: typescript, angular8

I use the following code to check if a string is null or defined.But even when the string has value it returns false.

```
  filename: string;

  validate(): boolean {
        if (this.filename) {
            this.error = true;
            this.message = "Please enter valid filename";
            return false
        }
        }
```

---

Update

This is how i bind the value

```
<input name="filename" id="filename" pr_ngcontent-oci-c5="" aria-label="filename" class="form-control" placeholder="File Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filename">
```

But sometimes,the breakpoint is never hit when the filename input is empty.Sometimes the code seems to work as intended.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on stackblitz? I looks like it has something to do with lifecycles or event loop queue.

Comment: @julianobrasil please take a look at the update..

Comment: why you don't use `formControls` instead of `ngModels` , and add a required `validator`

Comment: The initial value can be null or undefined for your property, but as soon as ngModel synchronizes the value, it is empty for an input. So if it is required you should also check for empty strings.

Comment: The issue seems to have sorted by itself now...

Comment: Where/how is the validate method being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Aymen TAGHLISSIA in the comments, a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) might be a more elegant way to implement a form and its validation. Here is an [Introduction to forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) and also an example using  [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) .

**Original answer:**

Rewrite your function as followed with `!this.filename`:

```
function validate(): boolean {

  if (!this.filename) {
    this.error = true;
    this.message = "Please enter valid filename";
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(validate(null)); // false
console.log(validate(undefined)); // false
console.log(validate('')); // false
console.log(validate('valid')); // true
```

Though you could also think about passing a string as parameter:

```
function validate(str: string): boolean {

  // Reset error and message?
  // ...      

  if (!str) {
    this.error = true;
    this.message = "Please enter non empty string";
    return false;
  }

  // Or reset error and message here
  // this.error = false;
  // this.message = undefined;

  return true;
}
```

And then something like:

```
if (!validate(this.filename)) {
  // Valid filename
} else {
  // Error
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `!this.filename`?

Comment: it seems to fix the issue... but i had tried with that earlier...